# object property to text

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I am retrieving a integer from my database which should correspond to a text string when output.

```
$sql = ('SELECT drinking, smoking FROM users WHERE id = ?')

$q = $this->db->query($sql, $this->session->userdata('user_id'));

if ($q->num_rows() === 1) {
    $userobject = $q->row();
}
```

This might get a value of 1 for drinking and 2 for smoking. I then want a function to turn that integer into a corresponding string. For example "Drinking at parties only" for drinking and "I dont smoke" for smoking.

I would like to have just one function that can handle this for all the properties.

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
$userobject->drinking = number_to_text($userobject->drinking);
```

And then have a function like this:

```
public function number_to_text()
{

}
```

But since this function is going to handle both drinking and smoking (and others too), then i would need to get the name of the property to get the right string.

How can that be done?

Hoping someone can help me (and understands me). If it can't be done this way i am open to suggestion af another way to do it.

Thankyou in advance

Comment: Just pass it as an argument, make `function number_to_text($value, $type_of_activity){ ... }`

Comment: Voitcus: I could do that of course, didn't think about that. But if its possible to get the name of the property instead, that would be a little easier? But if not, i will go for that

Comment: @JensAhlstenHerlevsen you can pass it as a string if you like. You can refer to that property using "variable variables", like `$this->{$property_name}` is `$this->drinking` if `$property_name == "drinking"`, `$this->smoking` if "smoking", `$this->anything_else` if "anything_else".

Comment: I think i am just gonna go with your first suggestion. Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: Here you are, with another (better) solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you requested in comments to this question, I put my suggestion, however, after re-think, there is a better solution that you can find below.

**First, as in my comment.**

You can simply pass the activity as an argument, for example declare your function as

```
function number_to_text($value, $type_of_activity){
  switch ($type_of_activity){
    case 'drinking': 
      switch($value){
        case 1: return "I'm drinking a lot"; break;
        case 2: return "I've never tasted alcohol, I'm too young for that"; break;
        //
      } // switch($value)
      break;
    case 'smoking':
      switch($value){
        case 1: return 'I smoke as a steam engine'; break;
        case 2: return 'I saw once a smoke and since then I keep away from it'; break;
        //
      } // switch($value)
      break;
  } // switch $type_of_activity
  return ''unknown';
}
```

But...

As you can see it's quite complicated statement.

**Second, the easier one.**

You can create an array with all of the texts like:

```
$activities['drinking'][1] = "I'm drinking a lot";
$activities['drinking'][2] = "I've never tasted alcohol, I'm too young for that";
$activities['smoking'][1] = "I smoke as a steam engine";
$activities['smoking'][2] = "I saw once a smoke and since then I keep away from it";
```

and just call it by

```
$activity = 'drinking';
$userobject->{$activity} = $activities[$activity][$userobject->{$activity}];
```

Much simpler I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Switch case and put your cases in that function. See I have made it an array response so ur property will be one key and value will be the string you want.

```
public function number_to_text($text)
{
    switch($text) {
        case 1:
        $arr['property'] = 'drinking';
        $arr['val']      =  "Drinking at parties only";
        return $arr;
        break;


}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. From the database i get a value of 1,2 or 3 from drinking for example.

If i then use the function for drinking i would like it to return a string of: 1: "Yes i am drinking", 2: "Only drink at parties", 3: "Never drink". But if i use the function for smoknig i would need them to say something different of course. So i need to know which property the function is called on.